# using bootstrap in asp.net 2015

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, visual-studio-2015

```
<div class="form-group ">
  <div class="col-md-offset-2" >
    <asp:Button id="btn1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="btn btn-info col-md-2"/>
    <asp:Button id="btn2" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="btn btn-success col-md-2"/>
```

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Control 'btn1' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with
>   runat=server.    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack
>   trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Control 'btn1' of type
>   'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Control 'btn1' of type 'Button' must be
>   placed inside a form tag with runat=server.]
>   System.Web.UI.Page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
>   +9726322    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +62
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +20
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +20
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +66
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children) +128
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +66
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +5827

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1038.0

Comment: <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2" >
                            <asp:Button id ="btn1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="btn btn-info col-md-2"/>  using this code
                            <asp:Button id="btn2" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="btn btn-success col-md-2"/>

Answer (score 0):

Add a form with `runat="server"` attribute.

```
<form runat="server">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-offset-2" >
        <asp:Button id="btn1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="btn btn-info col-md-2"/>
          <asp:Button id="btn2" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="btn btn-success col-md-2"/>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```